# Why does VBScript fail with a “Type mismatch" error?

Tags: vbscript, ldap

I am experiencing difficulty with the following VBS

```
set conn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
Conn.Open "ADs Provider"

strQueryDL = "<LDAP://company.address.com/cn=address>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));distinguishedName,adspath;subtree"
set objCmd = createobject("ADODB.Command")
objCmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
objCmd.Properties("SearchScope") = 2 ' we want to search everything
objCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 500 ' and we want our records in lots of 500 

objCmd.CommandText = strQueryDL
Set objRs = objCmd.Execute

While Not objRS.eof

wscript.echo objRS.Fields("distinguishedName")
' do something with objRS.Fields("distinguishedName")'
objRS.MoveNext

Wend
```

Please help me, I just started vbscripting and this was from an answer in this website.

```
wscript.echo objRS.Fields("distinguishedName")
```

The error was from the above line/code. How do I display out the field or convert it to display?

Comment: have you tried `objRS.Fields!distinguishedName` ?

Comment: that doesnt work. gives me `expected end of statement`

Answer (score 0):

`LDAP://company.address.com/cn=address` is not a valid LDAP URL (see [here](http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-path.htm#URL)). The search base must be a distinguished name, e.g.:

```
LDAP://company.address.com/cn=address,dc=address,dc=com
```

The distinguished name of the domain (`dc=address,dc=com`) can be obtained like this:

```
Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
WScript.Echo rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
```